# When building a fieldtype add-on, are you able to extend Grid?

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, grid

I wish to create my own fieldtype add-on (a fieldtype where users are able to create advanced, responsive layouts using simple tools in the backend). I currently do this without an add-on using Grid, with each row in my Grid field corresponding to a block of content on the page.

Basically, I was hoping to extend Grid with some additional logic, Javascript and CSS to create a more user friendly version of this. I can see in the database how Grid generally works and my question is whether I need to replicate this functionality with a custom table within the database or whether I can extend Grid's functionality?

Cheers to anyone who can help and sorry if some of my terminology is a little off - still learning my way around EE addons

Comment: Perhaps it'd be worth the $50 to just use Matrix? You'll kill yourself trying to write your own, and I really don't think extending the native Grid is going to be very feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm not after just the functionality of Matrix - I want to extend the functionality of Matrix (and Grid) to do more things with it

Comment: If you can provide more detail about what you're doing, it'd help. Likely, though, I think you're not going to be able to do anything that extends the Grid.

Comment: Have you tried it? A quick look at the grid fieldtype shows that itself extends EE_fieldtype, and it loads grid_model and grid_lib. Depending on what precisely you want to alter, it might or might not be possible.